# SoundCloud SDK on Swift, can't translate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdk, soundcloud

I need to use SoundCloud SDK into a Swift. Does someone have experience in this?
I have problem even at the start of their integration guide: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart#authentication

When, in AppDelegate, I write

```
var scurl: NSURL
scUrl = NSURL(string: "www.francescocrema.it")!
SCSoundCloud.setClientID(idCode,secret: secCode, redirectURL: scUrl)
```

when it gets executed, the app crashed with SIGABRT and no visible error!
Plus, I can't manage to translate this code to Swift

```
- (IBAction) login:(id) sender
{
SCLoginViewControllerCompletionHandler handler = ^(NSError *error) {
    if (SC_CANCELED(error)) {
        NSLog(@"Canceled!");
    } else if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Done!");
    }
};

[SCSoundCloud requestAccessWithPreparedAuthorizationURLHandler:^(NSURL *preparedURL) {
    SCLoginViewController *loginViewController;

    loginViewController = [SCLoginViewController
                           loginViewControllerWithPreparedURL:preparedURL
                                            completionHandler:handler];
    [self presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
}];
}
```

Does someone know more about SoundCloud API?
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid SoundCloud API is not longer maintain by its team. I would recommend you to use your own library. I am using SoundCloud API as well so I decided to create one, maybe it can be useful for you.

[ABMSoundCloudAPI on Github](https://github.com/andresbrun/ABMSoundCloudAPI)

Answer (score 0):

Your `redirectURL` is invalid.  `SCRequest` requires a URL with the scheme `https`:

```
NSAssert1([[aResource scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"], @"Resource '%@' is invalid because the scheme is not 'https'.", aResource);
```

Your Swift presentation code might look like this:

```
SCSoundCloud.requestAccess { (url) in
    let loginViewController = SCLoginViewController(preparedURL: preparedUrl, completionHandler: nil)
    self.present(loginViewController, animated: true)
}
```